# Apply lookup table to DataFrame for bins or ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like the below. Assume these are amounts of sales for a list of sales people.

[image]

Further, I have a lookup table that contains the commission by dollar amount. This looks like the below. So, $0-$50,000 = 5%, $50,001-$250,000 = 4%, etc.

[image]

What I want to do is apply the lookup table to the sales table to produce the below DataFrame.

[image]

Attempt 1:

```
In [66]: a
Out[66]: 
   Sales_1  Sales_2  Sales_3
0   200000   300000   100000
1   100000   500000   500000
2   400000  1000000   200000

In [67]: b
Out[67]: 
            Commission
Sales                 
50000             0.05
250000            0.04
750000            0.03
9999999999        0.02

In [68]: c = b['Commission'][a <= b.index.values]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-d229bce29f01>", line 1, in <module>
    c = b['Commission'][a <= b.index.values]

  File "C:\WinPython64bit\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1184, in f
    res = self._combine_const(other, func, raise_on_error=False)

  File "C:\WinPython64bit\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3555, in _combine_const
    raise_on_error=raise_on_error)

  File "C:\WinPython64bit\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2911, in eval
    return self.apply('eval', **kwargs)

  File "C:\WinPython64bit\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2890, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

  File "C:\WinPython64bit\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1132, in eval
    result = get_result(other)

  File "C:\WinPython64bit\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1103, in get_result
    result = func(values, other)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (4,)
```

Attempt 2:

```
In [59]: a
Out[59]: 
   Sales_1  Sales_2  Sales_3
0   200000   300000   100000
1   100000   500000   500000
2   400000  1000000   200000

In [60]: b
Out[60]: 
            Commission
Sales                 
50000             0.05
250000            0.04
750000            0.03
9999999999        0.02

In [61]: c = b.lookup(a['Sales_1'],['Commission'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-61-99e8134e826c>", line 1, in <module>
    c = b.lookup(a['Sales_1'],['Commission'])

  File "C:\WinPython64bit\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2649, in lookup
    raise ValueError('Row labels must have same size as column labels')

ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels
```

Can anyone help me in applying a lookup table to a DataFrame? It doesn't have to be exactly like this, but this illustrates my general need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To work with ranges, `pd.cut` is your friend. Based on your current `b` dataframe, you only have to amend the bins list you passed as an argument to define the lowest range. Here I put 0 as negative sales do not exist, but you could put any negative number too if needed, even deal with `-np.inf` and `np.inf` instead of `1E14` for your lower and upper boundaries:

```
pd.cut(a.stack(), [0] + b.Sales.tolist(), labels=b.Commission).unstack()
Out[39]: 
  Sales_1 Sales_2 Sales_3
0    0.04    0.03    0.04
1    0.04    0.03    0.03
2    0.03    0.02    0.04
```

I found `b` like below clearer to be used with cut:

```
          Sales  Commission
0          -inf         NaN
1         50000        0.05
2        250000        0.04
3        750000        0.03
4           inf        0.02
```

Arguments become then:

```
pd.cut(a.stack(), b.Sales, labels=b.Commission[1:]).unstack()
```

Comment: Great usage of `pd.cut`! +1 :-)

Comment: thanks. PS: I would really rearrange `b` to that I can pass b.Sales as such and `b.Commission[1:]` for better clarity

Comment: How should `b` be arranged @Boud? I'm happy to make this better/easier/more clear.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Boud - thank you. I think this answer is perfectly.

Comment: @Boud this method returns categorical data. Is there a way to convert that to float? I tried `pd.cut(a.stack(), b.Sales, labels=b.Commission[1:]).unstack().astype(float)`, but it returns `ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions`.

Comment: @Kyle   swap unstack and astype in your call

Comment: I believe it might be related to this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12861 . So keep casting back to float prior reshaping

Comment: @Boud, thank you for your help with this. I'm very new to python (you already knew that though), and have had a hell of a time figuring out how everything works. Slowly, but surely, things are starting to make a little sense.

Comment: Bonjour worries. Read a lot of documentation and further SO corresponding to these functions. Have fun

Answer (score 2):

@Boud already hit this one out of the park.  But here are my takes

## `numpy`

using `searchsorted`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    b.Commission.values[
        b.index.values.searchsorted(a.values.ravel())
    ].reshape(a.values.shape),
    a.index, a.columns)

   Sales_1  Sales_2  Sales_3
0     0.04     0.03     0.04
1     0.04     0.03     0.03
2     0.03     0.02     0.04
```

## `pandas`

using [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)
I'll `stack` `a` as well and also shift the boundary definitions

```
a_ = a.stack().sort_values().to_frame('Sales')
b_ = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Sales=np.append(0, b.index[:-1]),
        Commissions=b.Commission.values
    ))

print(a_)
print()
print(b_)

             Sales
0 Sales_3   100000
1 Sales_1   100000
0 Sales_1   200000
2 Sales_3   200000
0 Sales_2   300000
2 Sales_1   400000
1 Sales_2   500000
  Sales_3   500000
2 Sales_2  1000000

   Commissions   Sales
0         0.05       0
1         0.04   50000
2         0.03  250000
3         0.02  750000
```

Now we can use [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(a_, b_).set_index(a_.index).Commissions.unstack()

   Sales_1  Sales_2  Sales_3
0     0.04     0.03     0.04
1     0.04     0.03     0.03
2     0.03     0.02     0.04
```

---

***naive time test***

[image]

Comment: Yes, numpy is really fast ;)